# Spring data rest select Projection from user role

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest, projection

I have two projection

```
@Projection(name = "default",types = { People.class }) 
public interface DefaultPeople {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
}
```

and

```
@Projection(name = "privacy",types = { People.class }) 
public interface DefaultPeople {
    @Value("#{target.firstName.charAt(0)}")
    String getFirstName();
    @Value("#{target.lastName.charAt(0)}")
    String getLastName();
}
```

privacy projection print only first charater of firstname and lastname

i want :
ROLE_ADMIN access to projection default
and
ROLE_USER access to only projection pryvacy

is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. You need to implement the Controller to return different projection yourself.

Spring Data REST is not a silver bullet to solve all HTTP API problem. Just don't use it if it doesn't meet your requirement.